# RecyclerView row TextView line cutoff when displayed after a CheckBox

Tags: android

I have a RecyclerView with rows that display a Checkbox then a TextView.  When the CheckBox is included the TextView shifts down about 10dp and the bottom line is also truncated about 10dp. I would like the TextView to display in the correct location, at the top, and not truncate the text in the last line.  Please see the screenshot below:

[image: Screen shot]

**row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:padding="6dp"
                  android:background="#0FFF0F"
        >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkCompleteTask"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left"
            android:background="#FF00FF"
            android:text=""
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left"
            android:text="Here is an example of multi-line text.  Notice the top has padding of about 10dp and the botton is cut off by about the same amount.  This only occurs when the CheckBox to the left is present."
            android:background="#00FFFF"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a RelativeLayout to achieve what you wanted easily-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:background="#0FFF0F"
    >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkCompleteTask"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#FF00FF"
        android:text=""
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chkCompleteTask"
        android:text="Here is an example of multi-line text.  Notice the top has padding of about 10dp and the botton is cut off by about the same amount.  This only occurs when the CheckBox to the left is present."
        android:background="#00FFFF"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the result is shown below

[image]